# symofny3 why page doesn't work on prod env

Tags: php, symfony

I have simple MapBoundle register in AppKernel:

```
        public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            //  ...
            new Kajzar\MapBundle\KajzarMapBundle(),
```

In /app/config/routing.yml is:

```
kajzar_map:
    resource: "@KajzarMapBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

in  /Kajzar/MapBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php i have

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {

    return $this->render('KajzarMapBundle:Default:index.html.twig', [
                'request' => $request,
                    ]
    );
}
```

and it works in dev (http://localhost/app_dev.php), when i try type http://app.php i have 500 erros. What is wrong?

I have cleared cache by

```
 php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Comment: Check the error logs

Comment: remove the folder of app/cache/prod. More efficient than cache:clear which may not remove all the cache.

Comment: @JimL: thanks! 
It was critical: Exception thrown when handling an exception (InvalidArgumentException: The directory "/var/www/ed/var/cache/prod/annotations" is not writable.

Comment: np, some things your computer knows better than us :)

Comment: You means http://localhost/app.php ??

Comment: Yes, @abdiel. Now it's works fine, thx.